# How to cat the `MAAS Key` of a user via `maas shell`?

Tags: command-line, maas

When we login to MAAS web UI, we can see the user `MAAS Key` in the `Preferences` page. Is there any chance to cat it as a text via console command `maas shell`?!

Answer (score 2):

maas shell

```
>>> from apiclient.creds import convert_tuple_to_string
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from maasserver.models.user import get_creds_tuple
>>> admin = User.objects.get(username='admin')
>>> token = admin.tokens.all()[0]
>>> print convert_tuple_to_string(get_creds_tuple(token))
```

Comment: >>> from apiclient.creds import convert_tuple_to_string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named apiclient.creds